# Move files to new folder structure using Terminal

Tags: bash, shell

Simple question: I need to move images from an old directory structure to a new one using some shell script in Terminal. The old file structure is as follows:

```
Parent.Folder -- Folder1
                 Folder2
                 Folder3
```

In each FolderX, we have more folders:

```
Folder1 -- CAM1
           CAM2
           CAM3
```

In each CAM folder we have the images:

```
CAM1 -- image1.jpg
        image2.jpg
        image3.jpg
```

I need to switch the folder structure, so that:

```
Parent.Folder -- CAM1
                 CAM2
                 CAM3
```

Containing:

```
CAM1 -- Folder1 -- image1.jpg
                -- image2.jpg
                -- image3.jpg
     -- Folder2 -- ...etc...
     -- Folder3 -- ...etc...
```

The script would need to be dynamic as I need to apply it to many data sets of different sizes.

Appreciate any assistance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is pretty easy with nested loops, or even [`prename`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/prename/) . What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet as I have very little experience with terminal. At the moment I've been doing it manually, which isn't ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cd parent.folder
$ find . -type f
./Folder3/CAM2/image3.jpg
./Folder3/CAM2/image2.jpg
./Folder3/CAM2/image1.jpg
./Folder3/CAM1/image3.jpg
./Folder3/CAM1/image2.jpg
./Folder3/CAM1/image1.jpg
./Folder2/CAM3/image3.jpg
./Folder2/CAM3/image2.jpg
./Folder2/CAM3/image1.jpg
./Folder2/CAM2/image3.jpg
./Folder2/CAM2/image2.jpg
./Folder2/CAM2/image1.jpg
./Folder2/CAM1/image3.jpg
./Folder2/CAM1/image2.jpg
./Folder2/CAM1/image1.jpg
./Folder1/CAM3/image3.jpg
./Folder1/CAM3/image2.jpg
./Folder1/CAM3/image1.jpg
./Folder1/CAM2/image3.jpg
./Folder1/CAM2/image2.jpg
./Folder1/CAM2/image1.jpg
./Folder1/CAM1/image3.jpg
./Folder1/CAM1/image2.jpg
./Folder1/CAM1/image1.jpg

$ for i in Folder*/CAM*/; do
    mkdir -p "$(basename $i)";
    mv "$i" "$(basename "$i")/$(dirname "$i")";
  done

 $ find . -type f
./CAM3/Folder2/image3.jpg
./CAM3/Folder2/image2.jpg
./CAM3/Folder2/image1.jpg
./CAM3/Folder1/image3.jpg
./CAM3/Folder1/image2.jpg
./CAM3/Folder1/image1.jpg
./CAM2/Folder3/image3.jpg
./CAM2/Folder3/image2.jpg
./CAM2/Folder3/image1.jpg
./CAM2/Folder2/image3.jpg
./CAM2/Folder2/image2.jpg
./CAM2/Folder2/image1.jpg
./CAM2/Folder1/image3.jpg
./CAM2/Folder1/image2.jpg
./CAM2/Folder1/image1.jpg
./CAM1/Folder3/image3.jpg
./CAM1/Folder3/image2.jpg
./CAM1/Folder3/image1.jpg
./CAM1/Folder2/image3.jpg
./CAM1/Folder2/image2.jpg
./CAM1/Folder2/image1.jpg
./CAM1/Folder1/image3.jpg
./CAM1/Folder1/image2.jpg
./CAM1/Folder1/image1.jpg
```

Note that this code assumes certain folder structure that you have mentioned. If what you mentioned in the question is any different from reality, this might not work.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!